# error in connecting aws geoserver with aws postgres rds

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, postgis, geoserver

Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "{geoserver_ip}", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption) while I try to create a postgis data store in geoserver in AWS(similar error is coming in local geoserver too) although i could see postgres is accessible via pgadmin using the endpoints given in aws rds for the postgres

I have configured inbound and outbound rules and even fixed the route table and allowed all ALL traffic and All TCP in the rds too. As i can Access the shp files from pgadmin using the same endpoints why this error is coming up again and again when i am trying to connect it with geoserver.

Comment: An Amazon to Amazon connection will probably need to use the internal IP addresses, the best way to check is to use psql on the GeoServer box.

Answer (score 0):

Common issue I noticed is because  database is configured to allows only SSL connections  (parameter  rds.force_ssl set  to 1) but you try to establish connection without SSL/encryption from client. Can you try connection enabling encryption from geoserver ?

Comment: Yes, setting the SSL_MODE datastore parameter to "REQUIRE"